# (JAVA) SOAP WebService error object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

i am trying to set up connection to SOAP WebService from Android app but every time i get wried error in my result :
object reference not set to an instance of an object java
It seems to be error from server --> [SOAP Webservice call from Java gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046881/soap-webservice-call-from-java-gives-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of)

But when i try it throught web browser with POST request it works fine :)

This service http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx?op=ResolveIP

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";
private static String URL = "http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String name, String webMethName) {
    String resTxt = null;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set name
    sayHelloPI.setName("ipAddress");
    // Set Value
    sayHelloPI.setValue("88.212.35.129");
    // Set dataType
    sayHelloPI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(sayHelloPI);
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;  
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try{
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);  //webMethName = "ResolveIP"
        // Get the response
        Log.d("a", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
        //SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to resTxt variable static variable
        //resTxt = response.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
         //Print error
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I spend lot of time on google but i cant figure right answer why this happend

// EDIT
Finally i get it right ... idk why but when i send second parameter like this (i reuse old property) :

```
sayHelloPI.setName("licenseKey");
sayHelloPI.setValue("some_key");
sayHelloPI.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(sayHelloPI);
```

it wasnt working. But when i make new Property object it works:

```
PropertyInfo sayHelloPI1 = new PropertyInfo();
sayHelloPI1.setName("licenseKey");
sayHelloPI1.setValue("ds");
sayHelloPI1.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(sayHelloPI1);
```

Maybe it help someone next time

Comment: Are you using ksoap2?

Comment: yes i am, my friend. I know i can sipmly send POST request from android (because from browser, this way works) and i should works but i want send it like regular soap envelope

Answer (score 1):

This is some code that I have used myself - Hope it will help you:

```
        // Initialize soap request + add parameters
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(getString(R.string.Namespace),
                getString(R.string.Method_Name_GetStudentsByTeam));
        Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "SOAP request");

        // Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("teamId", params[0]);
        Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "id: " + params[0]);

        // Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask",
                "Declared the version of the SOAP request");

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "Setting som variables");
        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    getString(R.string.URL));
            Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "Instance the HttpTransportSE");

            // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(
                    getString(R.string.Soap_Action_GetStudentsByTeam),
                    envelope);
            Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "Called the Webservice");

            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "Got the Soapresult");

            if (result != null) {
                // Do something with result
                // success = true;
                Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "set sucess boolean to true");

                for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                    result.getPropertyInfo(i, pi);
                    Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask",
                            pi.name + " : " + result.getProperty(i));

                    SoapObject obj = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);

                    Student student = new Student();

                    student.address = obj.getProperty("Address").toString();

                    student.city = obj.getProperty("City").toString();
                    student.created = DateTime.parse(obj.getProperty(
                            "Created").toString());
                    student.dateOfBirth = DateTime.parse(obj.getProperty(
                            "DateOfBirth").toString());
                    student.email = obj.getProperty("Email").toString();
                    student.firstname = obj.getProperty("FirstName")
                            .toString();
                    student.id = Integer.parseInt(obj.getProperty("ID")
                            .toString());
                    student.imageId = Integer.parseInt(obj.getProperty(
                            "ImageID").toString());
                    // SoapObject lastNameObject = (SoapObject) obj
                    // .getProperty("LastName");
                    //
                    student.lastName = obj.getProperty("LastName")
                            .toString();

                    student.phone = obj.getProperty("Mobile").toString();

                    student.zipcode = obj.getProperty("PostalCode")
                            .toString();
                    student.schoolId = Integer.parseInt(obj
                            .getPropertyAsString("SchoolId"));
                    student.teamId = Integer.parseInt(obj
                            .getPropertyAsString("TeamId"));
                    student.testStarted = Integer.parseInt(obj
                            .getPropertyAsString("TestsStarted"));
                    student.timeStamp = DateTime.parse(obj
                            .getPropertyAsString("TimeStamp"));
                    student.image = getImage(Integer.parseInt(obj
                            .getProperty("ImageID").toString()));

                    if (student.image == null)
                        student.image = BitmapFactory
                                .decodeResource(getResources(),
                                        R.drawable.default_usericon);

                    MyApp.getController().addStudent(student);
                }

            } else {
                // If fails
                // success = false;
                Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "set login boolean to false");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("GetStudentsByTeamTask", "FAILED! " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```